# Iframe redirects to the source address

Tags: html, iframe

I have a simple Iframe with the source to the third party website I have provided in snippet below. When I insert this code into my own website, the parent page redirects to the source of Iframe (third party website) after a few seconds. But in the snippet below and codopen it does not redirect. What is the logic behind this difference and how can I overcome this? ([test URL in my website](http://www.taavonkhabar.com/details/?id=1&p=https&g=www.hamshahrionline.ir/news/450430/%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%87%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AF-%D9%85%D9%84%DB%8C-%D9%87%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B6%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%A7-%DB%B6-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%B1))

```html
<iframe name="myframe" src="https://www.hamshahrionline.ir/news/450430/صدور-کارت-هوشمند-ملی-همه-متقاضیان-تا-۶-ماه-دیگر" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sandboxing your `<iframe>`. For more details, refer to https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: Thank you it worked but how snippet here works without sandbox? I am looking for the reason of difference

Comment: Maybe, it picks a default config without using sandbox

Comment: @AliSheikhpour _“but how snippet here works without sandbox?”_ - it doesn’t; the snippet functionality here uses an iframe itself, and that iframe _has_ a sandbox set.